# How to work around this Matlab App Designer Error?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm getting this error every time I try to run an app from the App Designer:
"Unable to perform assignment because the left and the right sides have a different number of elements".
This happens even when the app is blank.

[Screenshot of Error even when running an empty app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX8qN.png)

Comment: Could you put also code view part ?

Comment: In the example I posted, I added nothing to the code... I just opened a blank template in the app designer, and it immediately shows me that when I try to run it